# Getting matrix from stored cells in MySQL table via query

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is run a query that will respond with the rooms matrix as an array. This will be used for path finding for moving a player across a room within a game. E.g. `[[0,1],[1,0]]`  I have stored the cells within room as X,Y and Walkable within the below table but needs to place the walkable data into the array at X and Y coordinate.

I am currently storing the data in this structure as a mysql table

```
CREATE TABLE MatrixCells (
ID int,
RoomID int,
Column int(2),
Row int(2),
Walkable bool,
PRIMARY KEY(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (RoomID) REFERENCES Rooms(ID) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

So storing the example array  `[[0,1],[1,0]]` will be stored like this. So what is the query required to generate the array as the returned result from the query

```
RoomID  Column Row Walkable
1       0       0   0
1       0       1   1
1       1       0   1
1       1       0   0
```

Comment: please add a sample output

Comment: Kinda thinking of something like this [[0,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]

Comment: But the 0/1 represents the Boolean value of walkable 0=false 1=true

Comment: Have you need a string as output?

Comment: Was thinking of an array

Comment: ok, please add more tags and more details to your question.